# Change am-time-ago if is greater than 1 day

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, date

I want to change am-time-ago if is greater than 1 day to :
A date DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm

my change in controller :

```
moment.locale('fr', {
  relativeTime : {
    future: "%s",
    past:   "%s",
    s:  "<1min",
    m:  "1min",
    mm: "%dmin",
    h:  "1h",
    hh: "%dh",
    d:  "1j",
    dd: "%dj", // Show DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm
    M:  "1m", // Show DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm
    MM: "%dm", // Show DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm
    y:  "1a", // Show DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm
    yy: "%da" // Show DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm
  }
});
```

My change in html :

```
<span class="label label-default" title="{{message.date | amDateFormat:'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'}}" am-time-ago="message.date"></span>
```

Looking forward to reading your answers, thanks in advince.

Comment: Refer the moment docs. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time/.
It seems you'll have to add a function to add custom date formats inside the relativeTime object.

Comment: Relative dates are a pain, just don't do it.

Comment: Thusitha you were right, it works thanks